# SharePoint Framework: How to build overlapping web parts?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

We have two web parts which are supposed to be used together. One can be placed above the other. The upper web part allows a drop down to be opened.

The problem: this drop down opens **under** the lower webpart. The user cannot interact with it:

[image: hidden drop down]

Two possible solutions are:

- somehow manipulate the z-index of the upper web part to be "higher" than the web part below it
- expand the height of the upper web part when the dropdown opens (looks weird though)

How is this supposed to be handled in the SharePoint Framework? Can I specify the base z-index of a web part? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would manipulate the z-index of the drop-down list. This isn't a SharePoint framwork specific problem, and there isn't a SharePoint framework specific solution.

Comment: I agree insofar that ideally we would set the z-index of the drop down. But unfortunately manipulating the z-index of the drop down list doesn't work. Apparently modifying the z-index of one of the web part containers (which are outside of the control of the web part) works. But I would classify this as not supported.

Comment: How is the drop-down list positioned?  z-index will only work on positioned elements (i.e. position:relative; or position:absolute).

Comment: I need to check this. It's a react control that is dynamically creating the popup.

Comment: The dropdown uses position:absolute. I modified it's z-index to high values - to no avail. It still disappears.

Comment: Not sure what else to try, but while I agree that changing the z-index of DOM elements inserted by SharePoint isn't technically supported, just doing that through CSS seems safe enough to me.